# SWR hook with next.js - typescript / issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

I've posted some questions about SWR hook here, because in my journey trying to use it has been a little bit hard since i'm having some problems with it

Now this time the error seems small.

**What i'm trying to do** is to git a breakpoint in my API triying to get some data, ( and i'm using axios by the way ) now the problem is that, i have to destructure `{data}` from the useSWR because that's the data i'm receiving from axios, and i think that is causing a problem with an argument that i have to pass to the hook in order to make everything work.

*Let me show you some code*

Using useSWR

```
const Part1 = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [searchBar, setSearchBar] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [userId, setUserId] = useState<dataObject>({});
  const [results, setResults] = useState<string>("");

  // Searchbar users

  useEffect(() => {
    const auth: dataObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth"));
    setUserId(auth);
  }, []);

  const { data }: multipleUsers = useSWR(
    () => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id,
    fetcher,
    "",
    data
  );
```

So as you can see, the last argument i pass to the function, is the name data because if i don't it would give me error ( as a mentioned before, i've posted a question about that problem ), and is this

```
Block-scoped variable 'data' used before its declaration.ts(2448)
Part1.tsx(41, 11): 'data' is declared here
```

**Goal**: what is going on there and how can i fixe that problem ? what is causing this specifically and why ?

Thanks for your time !!

**UPDATE**

I've changed my code, and this is the error that appears

```
 const { data }: multipleUsers = useSWR<user[]>(
    () => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id,
    fetcher,
    ""
  );
```

*ERROR*

```
Expected 4 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)
use-swr.d.ts(4, 99): An argument for 'Data' was not provided
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `useSWR` function signature ([source](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/src/use-swr.ts#L206-L216)):

```
function useSWR<Data = any, Error = any>(
  ...args:
    | readonly [Key]
    | readonly [Key, Fetcher<Data> | null]
    | readonly [Key, SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined]
    | readonly [
        Key,
        Fetcher<Data> | null,
        SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined
      ]
): SWRResponse<Data, Error>
```

You can pass the expected data type as the first type parameter, like so:

```
const { data } = useSWR<User[]>(
  () => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id,
  fetcher
)
```

Also note that you pass the function 4 parameters, but there's no override that supports 4 parameters, the maximum is 3, but could be less of course.

**Edit:**

Take a look at the `args` type again:

```
| readonly [Key]
| readonly [Key, Fetcher<Data> | null]
| readonly [Key, SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined]
| readonly [
    Key,
    Fetcher<Data> | null,
    SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined
  ]
```

There's only one variation which has 3 arguments, and it's this one:

```
readonly [
    Key,
    Fetcher<Data> | null,
    SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined
  ]
```

Take a look at the 3rd argument type:

```
SWRConfiguration<Data, Error> | undefined
```

Without even checking the source-code, it's probably some kind of object. What did you pass? An empty string: `""`.

Either remove this argument or pass a config object.

Comment: I changed my code to 

``````
const { data }: multipleUsers = useSWR<user[]>(
    () => "http://localhost:5000/api/user/allU/" + userId.user.id,
    fetcher,
    "",
  );
``````

But it would complain because there's no 4 argument

Comment: That's right, because you can *not* pass it 4 arguments, because it does *not* support a 4th argument, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I understand, but this is the error to explain what i'm trying to say

Expected 4 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)
use-swr.d.ts(4, 99): An argument for 'Data' was not provided

Comment: Please update your post with the updated code and the full error message.

Comment: @Diego You've accidentally suggested an edit to *my* answer. Please edit your *own* question post.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry for that, and i already updated my own post

Comment: Ok now i understand why there's no 4 argument, but i'm still kinda lost, am i supposed to give to 3rd argument the Data i'm expecting to receive ? like data<multipleUsers>

Comment: There's the regular arguments which go into the parentheses, i.e. `()`, and there's the type variables which go into the angle brackets, i.e. `<>`.

The first type variable of the `useSWR` function is the expected type of the response body, which is `User[]` in my example above, but probably `multipleUsers` in your case.

Regarding the 3rd (regular) argument, you probably don't need it, so you can just remove it.

Comment: The courses i've watched, in SWRconfig the would give as options the fetcher, and i did that ass well, but in my case it would complain about there no fetcher in the useSWR, so i cut the global config and started to give manually the fetcher, but now it's complaining about other arguments

Comment: Ok, i get it, i didn't know i could do that man, thanks for your answers ! it's been kinda hard trying to get this hook to work right.. jaja

Comment: TypeScript is not very simple and there's lots of places to get lost. Glad I could help!